# ScrollBars in my ScrollView does not show unless I touch the ScrollView

Tags: android

I have a layout that contains several items.

It contains a ScrollView.

Now, I want the ScrollBar to be always visible.

I have tried:

`android:fadeScrollbars="false"`

`android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true"`

`setVerticalScrollBarEnabled (false)`

`android:scrollbarFadeDuration="0"`

But the ScrollBar does not show, unless I touch the ScrollView (in that case it shows and stays as expected).

**Please I need the ScrollBar to be always visible (even if not touched),**

**so that the user knows that he can scroll that element.**

Thanks!!

---

EDIT EDIT EDIT
This is the full XML:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@color/mainbackground"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightSum="1" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/selector"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.1"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="1" >

    <TextView
        style="@style/T2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/month" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/byday"
        style="@style/T2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:background="@color/tertiarybackground"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/day"
        android:textColor="@color/links" />
</LinearLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/header"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/selector"
    android:layout_weight="0.1"
    android:background="@color/mainbackground" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/previous"
        android:layout_width="48dip"
        android:layout_height="48dip"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:background="@drawable/arrow_left" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        style="@style/H2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
        android:textColor="#000000" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/next"
        android:layout_width="48dip"
        android:layout_height="48dip"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:background="@drawable/arrow_right" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/daysoftheweek"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/header"
    android:layout_weight="0.05"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <TextView
            style="@style/T2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/sun" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <TextView
            style="@style/T2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/mon" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <TextView
            style="@style/T2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/tue" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <TextView
            style="@style/T2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/wed" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <TextView
            style="@style/T2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/thu" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <TextView
            style="@style/T2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/fri" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <TextView
            style="@style/T2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/sat" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<GridView
    android:id="@+id/gridview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/daysoftheweek"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_weight="0.5"
    android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
    android:numColumns="7"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth" />

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scroll"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.25"
    android:fadeScrollbars="false"
    android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawHorizontalTrack="true"
    android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true"
    android:scrollbarFadeDuration="0" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/GOTO"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="GOTO" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

---

This is the relevant java snippet:

```
rLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.text);

    ScrollView sv=(ScrollView)findViewById(R.id.scroll);
    sv. setScrollbarFadingEnabled(false);
    sv.requestFocus();
        if (((LinearLayout) rLayout).getChildCount() > 0) {
                ((LinearLayout) rLayout).removeAllViews();
            }
            desc = new ArrayList<String>();
            date = new ArrayList<String>();
            ((CalendarAdapter) parent.getAdapter()).setSelected(v);
            selectedGridDate = CalendarAdapter.dayString.get(position);
            String[] separatedTime = selectedGridDate.split("-");
            String gridvalueString = separatedTime[2].replaceFirst("^0*",
                    "");// taking last part of date. ie; 2 from 2012-12-02.
            int gridvalue = Integer.parseInt(gridvalueString);
            // navigate to next or previous month on clicking offdays.
            if ((gridvalue > 10) && (position < 8)) {
                setPreviousMonth();
                refreshCalendar();
            } else if ((gridvalue < 7) && (position > 28)) {
                setNextMonth();
                refreshCalendar();
            }
            ((CalendarAdapter) parent.getAdapter()).setSelected(v);
            selectedevents.clear();
            for (int i = 0; i < Utility.startDates.size(); i++) {
                if (Utility.startDates.get(i).equals(selectedGridDate)) {
                    desc.add(Utility.nameOfEvent.get(i));
                }
                if (sdf.format(events.get(i).dtstart).equalsIgnoreCase(
                        selectedGridDate)) {
                    selectedevents.add(events.get(i));
                }
            }

            if (desc.size() > 0) {
                for (int i = 0; i < selectedevents.size(); i++) {
                    LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(CalendarView.this);

                    View row = li.inflate(R.layout.event_row, null);
                    TextView eventname=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.eventname);
                    TextView eventtype=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.eventtype);

                    eventname.setText(selectedevents.get(i).title);
                    rLayout.addView(row);
                           }
```

Comment: On a separate note: Those are a lot of nested layouts you have there. You don't actually need to put a `TextView` in a `LinearLayout` just for positioning. For example, all of your children of `id/daysoftheweek` should be the `TextViews` themselves, rather than `LinearLayout`s.

Comment: @Lisa where is the code for adding new elements into scrollview.??

Comment: @Segi sorry Segi, just edited

Comment: @Lisa so now what... done.??

Comment: @Segi see at the end of the code `rLayout.addView(row);` thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

put below code in java file:

```
ScrollView.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(false);
```

and if stil not show scrollbar then put 
put below code in xml file:

```
android:scrollbarFadeDuration="0"
```

Comment: @Lisa its happening because of your height = 0dp.. just set height value to 40dp..

Comment: @Segi That's terrible advice. Using 0dp here because the weight is determining height.

Comment: @Lisa  its not displaying because there is only one button. just test it with putting 6 to 7 buttons into there..

Comment: @Segi the ScrollView is not empty, I populate it at runtime